# Spyder not importing basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, matplotlib-basemap

I have trouble to execute netCDF file and get error in spyder.  Here is what I get when I run the test.py script:

```
runfile('C:/Users/WINDOWS 8/Desktop/Testpython/test1.py', wdir='C:/Users/WINDOWS 8/Desktop/Testpython')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-c58f888280ee>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/WINDOWS 8/Desktop/Testpython/test1.py', wdir='C:/Users/WINDOWS 8/Desktop/Testpython')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 93, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/WINDOWS 8/Desktop/Testpython/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

I tried to uninstall an reinstall basemap from source, from apt-get, from conda, but it does not change anything: I can't import basemap.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks to me related to the pyproj module. Do you have all basemap dependencies installed and up to date ? You can check it with this command (requires pip)

```
pip install --upgrade --user matplotlib numpy pyproj pyshp OWSLib Pillow
```

It is actually a conda-related issue, please see [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/basemap-feedstock/issues/30).

Comment: I did, but still not working. I don't know why....

Comment: See the update in my answer.